Track video play in Elementor elements with GTM
I would like to track video plays events. I'm using WP and Elementor. I need to add an event listener but I don't know what the name of the event I'm looking for is.
Thanks everyone
For now I've written this:
<script>
    var vid = document.getElementsByClassName("elementor-video");
    var myvid= vid[0];
    myvid.addEventListener('play', function () {
        console.log("video_played");
        window.dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'video_play'
        });
    })
    <script/>

